# Any way to use a playlist as alarm signal on iPod touch?

Tags: ipod-touch

With my iPod nano 3G, I could use the alarm to start a playlist at a given time (e.g. for waking me up).

With my iPod Touch 2G (FW 3.0.1, not jail-broken), I can only choose from a list of pre-defined signals (like ring tones).

Is there any way to make the iPod touch use a playlist instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of 3.0, I would assume there's some application that can do this, but the default clock application cannot. I'd recommend searching the App Store for alarm applications and just reading the descriptions.

**Note:** While there may be an app that can do this, the drawback is that it cannot run in the background, meaning you would have to leave the clock app running the entire time.

If you're looking for an actual alarm clock, iHome carry some great alarm clocks that support using a custom playlist as your alarm when the iPod is docked. I've used one for a while with my 1st gen iPod Touch.

[image]

Comment: I have a Logitech docking station without clock and alarm. I'm very content with it, so I don't want to change it. But I can see that this could be a solution in some cases.

Comment: Well then I think your only solution is using a seperate app, and making sure you don't close out of it and leave it running all night or until you want the alarm to go off. A quick search on the app store reveals A+ Alarm Night Clock / Music and Alarm Clock! Music Themes Clocks that both allow you to wake to songs on a playlist.

Comment: Well, this is disappointing.